# Dynamic key in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im trying to create a dynamic group by (with sum agg) in MongoDB. But don't know how to right syntax that.

Lets imaging 2 documents:

```
{
"_id": {"$oid":"5f69f6a360c8479d0908a649"},
"key":"key1",
"data":{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    "key3":"value3",
    "key4":"value4"
    },
"count":10
}

{
"_id": {"$oid":"5f69f6a360c8479d0908a649"},
"key":"key2",
"data":{
    "key1":"value5",
    "key2":"value6",
    "key3":"value7",
    "key4":"value8"
    },
"count":15
}
```

With the key attribute, I want to control, which is the groupby attribute.

A pseudo query could look like:

```
[{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            '$key': data[$key]
        },
        sum: {
            '$sum': '$count'
        }
    }
}]
```

Output should look like:

```
value1 : 10    
value6 : 15
```

Somebody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the purpose of `$sum` and `$group`, there are no arrays in your documents.

This aggregation pipeline give desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { data: { $objectToArray: "$data" } } },
   { $set: { data: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$key"] } } } } },
   { $set: { data: { k: { $arrayElemAt: ["$data.v", 0] }, v: "$count" } } },
   { $set: { data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$data"] } } },
   { $unset: ["key", "count", "data"] }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `$reduce` input data as array using `$objectToArray`, check condition if key matches with data key then return key as value and value as count field
- convert that returned key and value object array to exact object using `$arrayToObject`
- replace field using `$replaceWith`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $arrayToObject: [
        [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
              initialValue: {},
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$key"] },
                  {
                    k: "$$this.v",
                    v: "$count"
                  },
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VVNeoTonaFg)